# Regular Expression to match from specified character to second line end

Tags: regex

i have text like this

```
aaa111
bbb222
ccc333
ddd444
```

and i need to match with Regular Expression from specified character to second new line
for example from bbb return like this :

```
ccc333
```

i used this code but not work fine

```
            string[] lines = input.Split('\n');
            string nums = "";
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                nums = lines.Length >= i ? lines[i - 1] : null;
                Match match = Regex.Match(nums, @"\bbbb\w*\b");
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex:

```bash
\bbbb.*\r?\n(.*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hgDV3S/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b`: Word boundary
- `bbb`: Match `bbb`
- `.*\r?\n(.*)`: Match any text followed by a line break followed by any text with 0 or more length. We capture last `(.*)` in group #1

**Code:**

```bash
string pattern = @"\bbbb.*\r?\n(.*)";
string input = @"aaa111
bbb222
ccc333
ddd444";
        
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) {
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]); // ccc333
}
```

[**Online Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/olxyer)

Comment: Thanks for sharing nice code sir, could you please do let me know if multiline enabling necessary in regex101 site and in code as well? Thank you.

Comment: @anubhava thanks it's working in regex but in my code only get first group before line break

Comment: @anubhava for example when the patern is aaa111 only return after line break bbb222

Comment: @anubhava I change may question when patter is bbb only need to get ccc333

Comment: @anubhava thanks but how can get Group 1 not Match 1 ?

Comment: ok check my updated code and a code demo

Answer (score 1):

If your data is well constrained, you can use

```
^bbb\d{3}\s\w{3}\d{3}$
```

[An explanation](https://regex101.com/r/L9HwW4/1)